# What is the meaning of $((M &amp ; 0x10000000))?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this line:

```
if [ $((M &amp ;0x10000000)) -eq 0 ]; then
```

But I don't know what is the meaning of this line. `M` is the variable which contains a number. But I don't know what `&amp ;  0x10000000` will do with is number.

Comment: Just a quick question. Why do you write `&amp;` and not just `&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyse your line step by step and look at `man bash` for answers:

- **`$(( expression ))`:**

  > *Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is `$((expression))`. The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially.  All tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion, string expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.  Arithmetic expansions may be nested. The evaluation is performed according to the rules listed below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If `expression` is invalid, bash prints a message indicating failure and no substitution occurs.*

  This tells us that we `M & 0x10000000` will be evaluated arithmetically.
- **`M & 0x10000000`:**

  > *The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances (see the `let` and declare builtin commands and `Arithmetic Expansion`).  Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error. The operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the C language.  The following list of operators is grouped into levels of equal-precedence operators.  The levels are listed in order of decreasing precedence.*
  >
  > ***`&`**      bitwise AND*

  This tell us that your variable `M` will undergo a [bitwise `AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation with the hexadecimal value `0x10000000`. The latter is the hexadecimal representation of 268435456 or 2^28. So in essence,the operation `M & 0x10000000` will return `0x10000000` if the 29th bit of `M` is set to `1` otherwise it will return `0x0` (note it is one bit more as 2^0 = 1).
- **`[ EXPRESSION ]`**: execution of the binary `/bin/test` Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

  > `INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2` `INTEGER1` is equal to `INTEGER2`

  This tells us that the expression `[ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ]` will return a `true` if the result of `M & 0x10000000` equals ZERO, otherwise it will return false.

So in short,

```
if [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ]; then
```

will perform a test on `M` to check if the 28th bit of `M` is set. If it is not set it will perform the action defined in the `if` statement.

An alternative notation would have been

```
if (( M & 0x10000000 == 0x0 )); then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is checking if the 29th bit of the number in `M` is clear.

```
$ M=0xEFFFFFFF; [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ] && echo CLEAR || echo SET
CLEAR
$ M=0xFFFFFFFF; [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ] && echo CLEAR || echo SET
SET
$ M=0x10000000; [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ] && echo CLEAR || echo SET
SET
$ M=0; [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ] && echo CLEAR || echo SET
CLEAR
```

The `&` is the bitwise and operator, it returns a number with the bits sets where the operands have both the same bits set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

More info about bitmasks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: thanks for your reply, so what  &amp is doing here?

Comment: `&` is the bitwise and operator

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

The `$((expression))` will do arithmetic expansion.

The line `if [ $((M & 0x10000000)) -eq 0 ]; then` will check if the 29th bit of `$M` variable is zero. If this is the case it will execute what follows `then` statement.